# ¿Como colocar el puntero en una coordenada X,Y especifica en un jTextArea?

Tags: java, jframe, cursor

Estoy creando un compilador, he creado una función que una vez que se halla colocado una llave de apertura "{" se coloque automáticamente la llave de cierre "}", el problema es que el cursor aparece después de haberse colocado esta ultima llave mencionada, de esta manera:

[image: Colocación errónea del puntero]

Cuando en realidad lo que yo busco es un resultado de esta manera:

[image: Colocación correcta del puntero]

Es decir, que necesito que el cursor aparezca después de haber escrito la primera llave de apertura.

Comment: Imagino que a tu compilador le estas generando un editor y es ahí donde tienes el problema. Por otro lado haría falta que mostrarás código para colocar el cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Podes utilizar `setCaretPosition(int position)` para moverte a una posición en particular dentro del texto ([setCaretPosition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition-int-)]). Entiendo que lo que buscas es que se acceda a una posición X-Y que sería como ir a la fila Y en la posicion X. Para lograr eso podrías usar `getCaretPosition()` luego de insertar los `{ }` y restar 2 posiciones o las que fuesen necesarias. No es lo mismo pero no se como estas manejando las filas y columnas de tu texto.

Otra alternativa podría ser que luego de las inserciones de `{ }` emules el keypress de la flecha hacia la izquierda tantas veces requieras. No es lo ideal pero es otra cosa que se me ocurre probar.